# Fail to instantiate the chaincode in first network of fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The official hyperledger fabric v1.0.0 gives a simple demo by using docker.

What i am doing is to avoid docker and directly run them on the machine. Thanks to the answer from my previous question, I have successfully launched 1 solo orderer, two peers (each from one org), created and joined the channels from peers, installed the chaincode on two peers.

The client side's command to install chaincode is

```
peer chaincode install -n myC1 -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
```

Both peers return the following message and I think it should be correct.

```
2017-09-11 16:34:26.361 SGT [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2017-09-11 16:34:26.361 SGT [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2017-09-11 16:34:26.556 SGT [main] main -> INFO 003 Exiting.....
```

However, when i try to instantiate the chaincode as follows

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7040 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n myC1 -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "OR  ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')
```

Client console returns the error message

```
2017-09-11 17:00:18.181 SGT [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2017-09-11 17:00:18.181 SGT [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode myC1:1.0)
```

The console of Peer0.org2 gives NO error message. But Peer0.org1's console gives the following:

```
2017-09-11 17:00:18.183 SGT [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 032 sending init failed(handler not found for chaincode myC1:1.0)
2017-09-11 17:00:18.184 SGT [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 033 failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"  on transaction a665c5305c5e3f158d272e4a39b04611e5335406e2a7c7057f11d32d8e07670e, error: Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode myC1:1.0)
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem and give me a simple explanation??

Comment: Which command did you use to start peer0 of both orgs? Any chance you've used --peer-chaincodedev flag?

Comment: I use 'peer start node'. I will try the flag tmr.

Comment: No, no need to use this flag I've just checked an assumption.

Comment: But any idea to solve this problem, bro?

Comment: how did you create and join the channel?

Comment: another question, are you running both peers on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. I run both peers and one solo orderer on a single machine.

Comment: have you configured different value for "fileSystemPath" peers config param?

Comment: I think I did so.

Comment: According to this error "Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode myC1:1.0)" it seems that chaincode container failed to start for some reason. Could you provide a bit more output? Also it will help if you can add output of "docker ps -a" and see if there chaincode container and in case it's do "docker logs chaincodeContainerID" and attach chaincode container output as well.

Comment: In wich directory are you locatek when you execute the install command? Have you define the variables (CHANNEL_NAME, ORDERER_CA) for the instantiate command?